# Ionic, home.html do not recognize <script>

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, ionic4

Hello i'm new to ionic ( ionic 4.1.1), but i still haven't found a way to implement javascript into my home.html, example : `

Waiting ...

```
<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
        <ion-refresher-content
    pullingText="Pull to refresh"
    refreshingText="Refreshing...">
    </ion-refresher-content>
</ion-refresher>

<script>
    alert('hey');
    var loops = setInterval(test ,3000);
    alert('heyy');
</script>

<br><br><br><br>

<button ion-button block (click)= "test(); test2()"> Test </button>
```

`

I've tried also to do it without all of the ions content & ions header ect...
But nothing work so...
did someone have the same bug/problem ?

Thanks for reading

Comment: @mehtankush there is no need to down vote, the question is pretty straight forward. He is trying to put js code in the view when it should instead go in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow MrPfalbo!

In Ionic, you place your javascript code in the corresponding `.ts` file of whatever page you are working on. Since you are on `home.html` you need to place your Javascript code in `home.ts`. The example code below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    alert('hey');
    var loops = setInterval(test ,3000);
    alert('heyy');
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes i see but, how do i call ioViewDidLoad in my .html ?

Comment: @MrPfalbo Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).